# Apple Mach-O-linker Error?

Tags: iphone, facebook, twitter, sharing

dear friends i added BMsocial.framework for sharing images to Face book ,tiwitter and Emai. so i added then build the project and i am getting following Apple Mach-O-linker error. and i am using xcode 4.5.1 and iOS 6 simulator.

```
Ld /Users/xxxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ShareExampleFramework-csgovwlrowaupgfvjrudqedpflug/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ShareExample.app/ShareExample normal i386
cd /Users/xxxxxx/Downloads/BMSocialShare-master/Examples/ShareExample
setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 4.0
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk -L/Users/xxxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ShareExampleFramework-csgovwlrowaupgfvjrudqedpflug/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/xxxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ShareExampleFramework-csgovwlrowaupgfvjrudqedpflug/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/xxxxxxx/Downloads/BMSocialShare-master/Examples/ShareExample/../../iOS/Binary -filelist /Users/xxxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ShareExampleFramework-csgovwlrowaupgfvjrudqedpflug/Build/Intermediates/ShareExampleFramework.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ShareExample.build/Objects-normal/i386/ShareExample.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=4.0 -framework Twitter -framework MessageUI -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework BMSocialShare -o /Users/xxxxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ShareExampleFramework-csgovwlrowaupgfvjrudqedpflug/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ShareExample.app/ShareExample

duplicate symbol _objc_retainedObject in:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/arc/libarclite_iphonesimulator.a(arclite.o)
/Users/xxxxxxx/Downloads/BMSocialShare-master/iOS/Binary/BMSocialShare.framework/BMSocialShare(BMSocialShare)
duplicate symbol _objc_unretainedObject in:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/arc/libarclite_iphonesimulator.a(arclite.o)
/Users/xxxxxxx/Downloads/BMSocialShare-master/iOS/Binary/BMSocialShare.framework/BMSocialShare(BMSocialShare)
 duplicate symbol _objc_unretainedPointer in:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/arc/libarclite_iphonesimulator.a(arclite.o)
/Users/xxxxxx/Downloads/BMSocialShare-master/iOS/Binary/BMSocialShare.framework/BMSocialShare(BMSocialShare)
 ld: 3 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Please Can any one help me for this error i am new to develop the Face book integration into iphone If it is not good frame work then give me some use full tutorial for develop sharing options

Thanks in Advance

Comment: you want for ios6 only? or other versions also?

Comment: for ios 5 and above versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know about BMsocial.framework.
For ios5 and above ShareKit is good.
check this
http://getsharekit.com/install/
If only for ios 6 then apple has added Social framework which support facebook, twitter sharing.

Comment: Ok thank you You for your reference i will try it share kit implementation